# How to use /callcap in visual studio 2008 for Visual C#

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, c#

I am developing a mobile application for Windows Smartphone devices in Visual C# (Visual Studio 2008). I would like to do code profiling and found /callcap compiler option available in MSDN. I would like to know how to use this option for my Visual C# project?
I tried to search this site and the internet but could not find any suitable answers.

Regards Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  `/callcap` is an option for the native compiler, not for managed code.  If you want to profile managed code, use something like the [Eqatec profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/).